# snmp unable to change tcpMaxConn.0 value

Tags: snmp

I'm trying change `tcpMaxConn.0` value in MIB by typing.

```
snmpset -v 3 localhost tcpMaxConn.0 i 300
```

But I gets error

```
Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: TCP-MIB::tcpMaxConn.0
```

I modify mib file `TCP-MIB.txt` and add read-write access in `tcpMaxConn` section, next restart server but still not workin. Where is error?

There is unset variables in MIBS which I set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the access attribute in the MIB file for this particular object it is not going to affect anything. The access control is implemented on the device side (in SNMP agent). The MIB file just contains the meta data which is used on the manager side to resolve OIDs to user friendly (display) names.

So if the certain object was not meant to be changed you will not be able to change it.